# npm WARN deprecated con react a crear un proyecto

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un error con instalar react y es cuando ejecuto este comando en la consola:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

me tira un error como este:

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 3s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: No son errores, son advertencias de paquetes o versiones obsoletos, seguido de información de seguridad, indicando que algunos paquetes contienen vulnerabilidades sin resolver.

Comment: WARN (warning) != ERR (error). Como mantra